# Float value is equal -1.#IND

Tags: python, floating-point, python-2.5

A function returns a `list` which contains of `float` values. If I plot this list, I see that some of the `float` values are equal `-1.#IND`. I also checked the type of those `-1.#IND` values. And they are also of `float` type.
But how can I understand this `-1.#IND` values? What do they represent or stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-1.#IND` means indefinite, the result of a floating point equation that doesn't have a solution. On other platforms, you'd get `NaN` instead, meaning 'not a number', `-1.#IND` is specific to Windows. On Python 2.5 on Linux I get:

```
>>> 1e300 * 1e300 * 0
-nan
```

You'll only find this on python versions 2.5 and before, on Windows platforms. The `float()` code was improved in [python 2.6](http://bugs.python.org/issue1635) and consistently uses `float('nan')` for such results; mostly because there was no way to turn `1.#INF` and `-1.#IND` back into an actual `float()` instance again:

```
>>> repr(inf)
'1.#INF'
>>> float(_)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.#INF
>>> repr(nan)
'-1.#IND'
>>> float(_)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): -1.#IND
```

On versions 2.6 and newer this has all been cleaned up and made consistent:

```
>>> 1e300 * 1e300 * 0
nan
>>> 1e300 * 1e300
inf
>>> 1e300 * 1e300 * -1
-inf
```